# Magento Add External CSS in local.xml

Tags: css, xml, magento, local, skin

I have the following file

url/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/productslider/widget/slider.phtml

That should use the css located in 
url/var/www/html/skin/frontend/boilerplate/default/productslider/css/less-compiled.css
url/var/www/html/skin/frontend/boilerplate/default/productslider/css/sass-compiled.css

There is a way to add my external .css through local.xml ?

I tried with

```
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel">
        <rel>stylesheet</rel>
        <href>http://cerrajerianecochea.com.ar//var/www/html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/productslider/widget/css/sass-compiled.css</href>
    </action>
</reference>



 <reference name="head">
    <action method="addLinkRel2">
        <rel>stylesheet</rel>
        <href>http://cerrajerianecochea.com.ar//var/www/html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/productslider/widget/css/less-compiled.css</href>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem its clear my friend when i make the relation between css and the phtml file , the file do not recognize the css

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>css/yourCssfile.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Please include explanation as to why this is the solution. It is more important to communicate the underlying logic than just the code by itself. That way, others can understand the solution, avoid similar problems, and adjust the code to fit their own needs. You're not just answering the OP - you're answering the world! :)

Comment: I apologize for not having much free time as you. The css It is added as is included in any html/php page. In the current case a .phtml file.

Comment: It's not really a matter of having a lot of free time. Taking an extra minute or two on your answer, as you did on your question, gives back to the community you're part of. I don't usually have much time either, so I know what that's like.  (Also, didn't notice you were the OP, as this was in the review queue. Same concept either way though.) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding them as text in the head section instead, like this;

```
<reference name="head">
<block type="core/text" name="uniquename">
    <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link href="http://cerrajerianecochea.com.ar//var/www/html/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/productslider/widget/css/sass-compiled.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>]]></text></action>
</block>
```

If these will load on a secure and non secure page, ommit the http: from the link

Comment: Should i call this in my phtml file ?

Comment: put it in your local.xml in the correct container for where you want it load